# How To fetch value from one table to another table in one to many Relationships in Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

How to access Balance value When Type Mobile Number?

## Image is

[image]

## Output Is

Enter Mobile No.Should be Return Balance Of Account Table.

Thank You

Comment: can you post your code (fetch command etc)?

Comment: Please tell me how to access balance of Account Table using Person ID .

Comment: As a person can have multiple accounts, which balance do you want to get? All? Also, the naming of the relationships should be inverted: person<->accounts.

Comment: I have add three person with different name with different balance.When I enter 1st person Should give me first Person's Balance,enter 2nd person Should give me second Person's Balance.Like wise continue...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390606/how-to-fetch-specific-data-in-one-to-many-core-data-relationships?noredirect=1#comment69983559_41390606 please please follow this link.I put whole details,Thank you